# Adobe Flash cs6 - How to make text unselectable?

Tags: flash, adobe-flash

When you want to make button in Flash, you don't want the user click the button but the text on the button becomes highlight, yet the button isn't pressed - That gonna drive people insane.

I have found some other people have this same problem (for example: [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1420824)), but their solution is some code, I don't want that, I want something simple. So how to simply make the text in flash unselectable?

Comment: People still use Flash?

Comment: @Tetsujin I even use Macromedia Flash 8.

Comment: Flash has been banned from the building here for over 2 years :/

Comment: If you use CryEngine Scaleform, the best solution is Adobe Flash CS6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the text by clicking on it.
2. Go to `Properties` of the text.
3. Click the `Ab` icon to turn off the `selectable` feature of the text.

[image: Make text unselectable]

**Note**: remember to make text unselectable for each frame of the button
[image: Text on all frame]